# add percentage on value using selectbox and javascript

Tags: jquery, forms, input, percentage

i have 2 inputs and 1 select box. in the select box i have 4 percentages 0.05 stands for 5% etc

1 input is purchase price. the other one must be the purcase price plus the percentage. I tried making it but my code does not work. this is the HTML

```
                        <table width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" width="16%" height="30">

                                PURCHASE<BR />
                                <input class="textbox" type="text" name="purchase_price" id="purchase_price" value="{if $smarty.get.eid neq ''}{$menudet[0].purchase|stripslashes}{/if}" />


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" width="16%" height="30">
                                INCREASE %<BR />
                                <select id="percentage" class="percentage">
                                  <option value="0.05">5%</option>
                                  <option value="0.10">10%</option>
                                  <option value="0.15">15%</option>
                                  <option value="0.20">20%</option>
                                </select>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td align="left" width="16%" height="30">
                                SELL PRICE<BR />
                                <input class="textbox" type="text" name="menu_price" id="menu_price" value="{if $smarty.get.eid neq ''}{$menudet[0].menu_price|stripslashes}{/if}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

and this is the javascript (should i also do this onDocload? or does it not matter because onchange is a function?

```
    {literal}
<script>

$("#percentage").change(function() {
    var perc = $("#purchase_price").val;
    var purch = $("#percentage").val;

    $("#menu_price").val(((purch * perc) + purch));
});
{/literal}
```

now it does nothing...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `.val` to `.val()`

```
<table width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="16%" height="30">

            PURCHASE<BR />
            <input class="textbox" type="text" name="purchase_price" id="purchase_price" value="{if $smarty.get.eid neq ''}{$menudet[0].purchase|stripslashes}{/if}" />


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="16%" height="30">
            INCREASE %<BR />
            <select id="percentage" class="percentage">
                <option value="1.05">5
                    %</option>
                <option value="1.10">10%</option>
                <option value="1.15">15%</option>
                <option value="1.20">20%</option>
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="16%" height="30">
            SELL PRICE<BR />
            <input class="textbox" type="text" name="menu_price" id="menu_price" value="{if $smarty.get.eid neq ''}{$menudet[0].menu_price|stripslashes}{/if}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$("#percentage").change(function () {
    var perc = parseFloat($("#purchase_price").val());
    var purch = parseFloat($("#percentage").val());

    $("#menu_price").val((purch * perc).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: changed it.. but the #menu_price does not change when i input some purchase price and select a percentage.. it must change on the fly

Comment: added on document ready now it works... but the calculation is wrong. when i enter 10 and select 10% it shows 10.10

Comment: Hi... it does work if i put 10 purchase and increase 10% it shows 11.. but if i put 10,35 and do the same it also shows 11.... and also the 5% does not work also... but my guess it because it rounds the numbers but,  i need digits with 2 decimals X,XX ... so im gonna remove floor and check again

Comment: removed the Math.floor ... now it works.. but if i do 10 and add 5% it shows 10.5 ... but it must show 10.50 ..how can i do this ?

Comment: I fixed it like this $("#menu_price").val(Math.round(purch*perc*100)/100); ... dont know if  yours is better.. but anyway you led me to the right way :)